# como preguntar por una lista en prolog

Tags: prolog

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en prolog en donde se especifique el nombre de una lista, que ya esta en la base de conocimiento, y que me diga si cierto elemento esta dentro de dicha lista. Por poner un ejemplo:

```
?-es(green_day,rock).
true.
```

Esta seria la respuesta que busco. Mientras en el codigo tendria algo como:

```
green_day=[rock,punk].

es(X,Y):- member(Y,X).
```

Esto ya lo he probado, daria "false" ya que el lo que hace es esperar que le pases por parametro una lista en si, no una referencia a una lista ya existente dentro de la base de conocimiento, por lo que devuelve false puesto que "green_day" no es ni una lista ni contiene "rock".

Entonces mi duda seria si existe alguna forma de que desde que se hace la consulta se pueda hacer referencia a una lista ya existente?.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que podrías estructurar de otra forma tu base de conocimiento, por ejemplo:

```
lists(green_day, [rock, punk]).
```

de esa forma podrías consultar de la siguiente manera:

```
es(X,Y):-
    lists(X, List), member(Y, List).
```

salida:

```
?- es(green_day, pop).
false.

?- es(green_day, punk).
true.
```

Recordá que en prolog las variables comienzan con mayúsucula, por lo que no estás definiendo correctamente esta línea en tu código `green_day=[rock,punk]`.